# Vercel maximum number of projects?

Tags: github, hosting, vercel

Does vercel have a maximum number of projects in the hobby plan? I know that you can import a maximum of three GitHub repositories. Does that mean that you can create a maximum of three projects. or is it possible to host more than three projects in vercel?

Answer (score 13):

EDIT: Please refer to the [official documentation](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/limits/overview) for further information ([link](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/limits/overview)).

No hard limits at this point. You can also import as many GitHub projects as you want. However, given a single repository, you can only create 3 Vercel projects with it in your **personal account**. For **team accounts** the current number is 10.

Example:

- You have a monorepo with a Next.js application and other applications. You can re-use the repository to create 3 Vercel projects. A commit from the repository will trigger builds on all 3 projects;
- You can have 100s of GitHub repositories connected to Vercel.

Be aware of API rate limits as well, which you can find [here](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/limits/overview).

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. Say I have an organization repo with 15 websites I've made for 15 clients. I wouldn't be able to use vercel to host any of them because Vercel has a cap at 10 projects per repo. 

If each website is its own repo, that means I can only have 10 websites hosted on vercel because vercel requires you to make a new project for whenever you create a new vercel site.

Comment: Perhaps something like https://github.com/vercel/platforms is more suited for that? One commit would generate ~15 preview deployments. A single project would be better for that IMO.
I would recommend giving this feedback to the company directly from the dashboard. On the top right of your dashboard, there is a "Feedback" button.

Comment: The wording messed me up. The rule you have on Vercel only applies to monorepos. The way it is worded makes it sound like you can only ever have 10 projects total which isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the max number of projects, these are the current limits per account type:

|  | Hobby | Pro | Enterprise |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Projects | 200 | Unlimited | Unlimited |
| Projects Connected per Git Repository | 3 | 60 | Custom |

[Here](https://vercel.com/docs/limits/overview#) you can find a list of all limits and limitations that apply on Vercel.